# Easiest way to print hundreds of same letter with different addresses

Tags: microsoft-word, csv, mail-merge, mailing-lists

There is a long list of names and addresses in CSV format (could be converted to a different). I need to print a hundred of letters with some formatting like:

```
%address%

Dear %name%,

Blah-blah-blah
```

How can I make Word or any other software print these letters using data from the list?

Answer (score 3):

It's called a [mail merge](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/word-mail-merge-a-walk-through-the-process-HA001034920.aspx).

You can use Excel as your data source, since you already have everything in a CSV.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this both with word and it appeared to be quite unreliable and complicated. E.g. I cannot realize what exactly should be in the excel sheet to have it picked up by word. I there any alternative way, maybe not with word at all?